# Submit search query along with another form

Tags: jquery, django, forms, search, django-forms

I have a Web page where there is a form with filters. On submitting this form, a table with the results is displayed. I want to add a search field in a second form above the table, which when submitted, further eliminates the results. How can the search query be submitted along with the filters' values simultaneously and vice versa?  Is there a non js way to do this as well?

**Initial filter form:**

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' %}"> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="span-after-btn disabled">
        <input class="disabled" id="distance-toggle" name="distance-toggle" type="checkbox" checked="" disabled="disabled" autocomplete="off">
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Search form:**

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'same url' %}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="search-term" type="text" class="form-control" name="search-term" placeholder="{% trans 'aaaaaaa' %}">
                <span id="span-search-btn" class="input-group-addon">
                    <button id="search-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-round" type="submit">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i> 
                    </button>
                </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Code? More details?

Answer (score 0):

Once you submit the form, the first table is shown with another form. On submit you could call a javascript function that further processes your data. If it requires data to be fetched you could implement an ajax call.

I'm not totally sure if I'm getting what you're saying though.